# How can i generate different numbers using Python3.9s random module

Tags: python, random

I did this beginner project a few weeks back where i made a random number generator that generates infinite numbers. i used the random module and figured it out from the docs (this was my first proj i was very proud of myself). So now i want to use it for more practical things. i tried to recreate it, and when the script is run it only generates one number and repeatedly prints that number to the terminal. nothing is wrong with the module, i belive, i think its a problem with my script but i cannot(for the life of me) figure out whats wrong.

this is my script

```
#number is the number the user enters this is here for other uses
number = input('Enter your number. >>> ')
#guess is the computers guess
guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)

while number != guess:
    print(guess)
```

this is my terminal

```
347
347
347
347
347
347
347
347
347
```

ect..(im not gonna type a ton of these you get the idea)

is there anything i can do to make it generate different numbers?

this is the module im using:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: see this guide to while loops: https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/. if you want guess to change in each iteration of the while loop, you need to create the random number in the loop!

Comment: Welccome to SO :) When providing code example try to make them [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)s so the community can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `guess` assignment is outside of your loop.

Looking at your code

```py
import random

# `number` is a string
number = input('Enter your number. >>> ')

# `guess` is only set here 
guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)

while number != guess:
    # `guess` does not change here
    print(guess)
```

What you probably want is something like

```py
import random

# parse input as a number
number = int( input( 'Enter your number. >>> ' ) )

# `guess` is initialized here
guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)

while number != guess:
    # reassign `guess`
    guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    print(guess)
```

Note the order of the loop here too though. If `guess` is correct on the first try nothing will be printed. You likely want to add a statement once `guess` is correct saying something like `You're number was: <number>`.

Comment: hi,
thanks for your input. this worked
for the if guess is correct i have this but it doesnt seem to work.

```if number == guess:
    print(f'Was your number {guess}')```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify what your question is.

Comment: Hi,
ignore that comment idr what i was asking. but i have my while loop:
```while number != guess:
    # reassign `guess`
    guess = random.randrange(1, 10)
    print(guess)
    if number == guess:
        print(f'Was your number {guess}')```
and it doesnt stop when the number is = to the guess. i can see it in the terminal and it still doesnt register. i tried using continue and i tried getting rid of the if statement and making it into a while-else statemtn (while: 
#stuff
else:
#stuff)
but it doenst work

Comment: It could be because you're not parsing the use input into a number. When you receive input it comes as a string, so you probably want to do something like `number = int( input( "Enter your number." ) )`. I left this out of the code example as it wasn't in your original code posting.

Comment: You probably also want to add a check that the received number is within the range you are guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You only set the value of `guess` once outside of your loop.  Therefore, it never changes and hence your loop never ends.  What you need to do is generate a new guess for each iteration:

```py
guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)

while number != guess:
    print(guess)
    guess = random.randrange(1, 1000)
```